# How do I consolidate the amount of times my website is shown on Google to just my homepage?

Tags: seo, google, homepage, search-results

We have a website that is reasonably new. When you search for the three words that make up the URL of the website we come up as the first four or five hits on Google.

We would like to consolidate these so that we only come up once, as our homepage. There are also specific product page of our website that some up before our homepage where we would like people to land on our homepage.

Do you guys know of a way we can try to consolidate the returns for the other pages?

Comment: Presumably these 3 words also appear on the page? These 4 or 5 pages in the SERPS are all on the same subdomain? I find this a bit strange... it is unusual that Google would return more than 2 pages from any one site. I always thought that this was something that Google actively tries to prevent?

Comment: Hi TRBC, did any of the below answers help?

Answer (score 1):

Many webmasters desperately try to get deep links to their site in Google SERPs. This is a show of confidence from Google that they feel this is what people want when searching for you. I have a similar situation when you [Google me](http://scotthel.me/googleme). I generally have the top 2 or 3 spots in Google SERPs. Occupying the top x number of results is better than occupying just the top spot.

Google may eventually turn this into Site Links, [which look like this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=amazon) (see the top result for Amazon).

Personally I wouldn't make any efforts to stop/remove this valuable asset.

*Edit*

To answer the question though, you can sign up for a [Google Webmaster](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) account and request that they do not index the pages in question. This will, after possibly a few weeks, remove the URLs specified from SERPs.

Answer (score 1):

As Scott Helme answers, it is very unusual not to want more real estate in the Google SERPs.   Most webmaster are happy to have multiple links to their site in the search results.   Most websites sell more product or otherwise perform better when they allow the user to land on the most relevant page.

If you really want to discourage search engines from linking to results other then your home page then there are some possible actions that you can take.  Any of the following should do the trick:

- Put [robots noindex meta tags](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) in the pages other than the home page.
- List the pages you don't want to have indexed in `robots.txt` (which will usually prevent them from being indexed unless they have lots of external links)
- Combine all your pages into one page.   You could even use JavaScript to hide and show parts of the page, or load additional content via AJAX.